# Setting row height in huxtable

Tags: r, expss, huxtable

I'm using the `expss` package to generate tables and then passing them to `huxtable`   This works fine but `height` function does not seem to work. Any insights? This occurs regardless of using a theme or exporting to HTML or Word.

```
t<-mpg %>% tab_cells(hwy,displ) %>%
  tab_rows(manufacturer) %>% 
  tab_stat_mean() %>%
  tab_pivot() %>% 
  set_caption("Car Stats") %>% 
  as_huxtable() %>% 
  set_col_width(1,.1)  %>%
  theme_article()

height(t)<-0.1   # if I change this to 0.2 I get the same result...

t
```

Answer (score 1):

The row height minimum is 1.0.  To place rows closer together, use `padding` as shown below:

```
mpg %>% tab_cells(hwy,displ) %>%
  tab_rows(manufacturer) %>% 
  tab_stat_mean() %>%
  tab_pivot() %>% 
  set_caption("Car Stats") %>% 
  as_huxtable() %>% 
  set_top_padding(.2) %>%
  set_bottom_padding(.2) %>% 
  theme_article()
```